# Get number of EC2 instances mounted on EFS - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Is there a way to find the names and number of EC2 instances that have an EFS mounted on them, through code or UI?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no direct command to do it, Here is one of the way using ansible and [Dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) configured.

Command:

```
ansible all -u ec2-user -a "grep efs /etc/fstab" | grep efs | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
2 file-system-id.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com:/ /var/www/html/efs-mount-point nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 0 0
1 test1.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com:/ /var/www/html/efs-mount-point nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 0 0
1 test2.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com:/ /var/www/html/efs-mount-point nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it seems insane to me that they don't have a UI or API for this.
If you're using knife, you can run a similar query, which I have listed below:

`knife ssh -a hostname 'name:*' "mount | grep \"\.efs\.\""`

Just a note that the answer above greps `/etc/fstab`, which will only return you machines that auto-mount this drive, rather than using `mount`, which will return machines which currently have this drive mounted.  Each is good at answering different questions.